# EclipseLink GeneratedValue null on postgres only on one entity

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have a rather weird case. I have some entities generated with netbeans and i can persist all except one. I see no difference in the database nor in the entity class. Can someone help me, here is my entity class , database, and error that i am receiving

```
CREATE TABLE objekat
(
  id_objekat bigserial NOT NULL,
id_opstina serial NOT NULL,
naziv character varying(50) NOT NULL,
kapacitet character varying(50),
adresa character varying(100),
lokacija_sirina double precision,
lokacija_duzina double precision,
opis character varying(500),
korisnicko_ime character varying(50),
sifra character varying(50),
maks_broj_slike integer,
absolute_path_logo character varying(255),
CONSTRAINT objekat_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_objekat),
CONSTRAINT fkobjekat924176 FOREIGN KEY (id_opstina)
  REFERENCES opstina (id_opstina) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and this is my entity bean.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objekat")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByIdObjekat", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE o.idObjekat = :idObjekat"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByNaziv", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE upper (o.naziv) like upper(:naziv)"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByNazivAndOpstina", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o inner join o.idOpstina op WHERE upper (o.naziv) like upper(:naziv) and op.idOpstina = :idOpstina"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByKapacitet", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE o.kapacitet = :kapacitet"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByAdresa", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE o.adresa = :adresa"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByLokacijaSirina", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE o.lokacijaSirina = :lokacijaSirina"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Objekat.findByLokacijaDuzina", query = "SELECT o FROM Objekat o WHERE o.lokacijaDuzina = :lokacijaDuzina")})
public class Objekat implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_objekat",columnDefinition = "BIGSERIAL")
private Long idObjekat;

@Size(max = 255)
@Column(name = "absolute_path_logo")
private String absolutePathLogo;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "objekatidObjekat")
private List<DogadjajObjekat> dogadjajObjekatList;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "objekatidObjekat")
private List<SlikeLokacijaObjekat> slikeLokacijaObjekatList;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "idObjekat")
private List<RasporedObjekat> rasporedObjekatList;
@Column(name = "maks_broj_slike")
private Integer maksBrojSlike;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "korisnicko_ime")
private String korisnickoIme;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "sifra")
private String sifra;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "opis")
private String opis;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "lokacija_sirina")
private Double lokacijaSirina;
@Column(name = "lokacija_duzina")
private Double lokacijaDuzina;



@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "naziv")
private String naziv;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "kapacitet")
private String kapacitet;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "adresa")
private String adresa;
@JoinTable(name = "tip_objekta_objekat", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "objekatid_objekat", referencedColumnName = "id_objekat")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "tip_objektaid_tip_objekta", referencedColumnName = "id_tip_objekta")})
@ManyToMany
private List<TipObjekta> tipObjektaList;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_opstina", referencedColumnName = "id_opstina")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Opstina idOpstina;

public Objekat() {
}

public Objekat(Long idObjekat) {
    this.idObjekat = idObjekat;
}

public Objekat(Long idObjekat, String naziv) {
    this.idObjekat = idObjekat;
    this.naziv = naziv;
}

public Long getIdObjekat() {
    return idObjekat;
}

public void setIdObjekat(Long idObjekat) {
    this.idObjekat = idObjekat;
}

public String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}

public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
}

public String getKapacitet() {
    return kapacitet;
}

public void setKapacitet(String kapacitet) {
    this.kapacitet = kapacitet;
}

public String getAdresa() {
    return adresa;
}

public void setAdresa(String adresa) {
    this.adresa = adresa;
}



@XmlTransient
public List<TipObjekta> getTipObjektaList() {
    return tipObjektaList;
}

public void setTipObjektaList(List<TipObjekta> tipObjektaList) {
    this.tipObjektaList = tipObjektaList;
}




public Opstina getIdOpstina() {
    return idOpstina;
}

public void setIdOpstina(Opstina idOpstina) {
    this.idOpstina = idOpstina;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idObjekat != null ? idObjekat.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Objekat)) {
        return false;
    }
    Objekat other = (Objekat) object;
    if ((this.idObjekat == null && other.idObjekat != null) || (this.idObjekat != null && !this.idObjekat.equals(other.idObjekat))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "rs.dzetSet.entiteti.Objekat[ idObjekat=" + idObjekat + " ]";
}

public String getOpis() {
    return opis;
}

public void setOpis(String opis) {
    this.opis = opis;
}

public Double getLokacijaSirina() {
    return lokacijaSirina;
}

public void setLokacijaSirina(Double lokacijaSirina) {
    this.lokacijaSirina = lokacijaSirina;
}

public Double getLokacijaDuzina() {
    return lokacijaDuzina;
}

public void setLokacijaDuzina(Double lokacijaDuzina) {
    this.lokacijaDuzina = lokacijaDuzina;
}


public String getKorisnickoIme() {
    return korisnickoIme;
}

public void setKorisnickoIme(String korisnickoIme) {
    this.korisnickoIme = korisnickoIme;
}

public String getSifra() {
    return sifra;
}

public void setSifra(String sifra) {
    this.sifra = sifra;
}


public Integer getMaksBrojSlike() {
    return maksBrojSlike;
}

public void setMaksBrojSlike(Integer maksBrojSlike) {
    this.maksBrojSlike = maksBrojSlike;
}

public void pocevajMaksBrojSlike(){
    this.maksBrojSlike++;
}

public String getAbsolutePathLogo() {
    return absolutePathLogo;
}

public void setAbsolutePathLogo(String absolutePathLogo) {
    this.absolutePathLogo = absolutePathLogo;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<RasporedObjekat> rasporedObjekatListPrePodne(){
List<RasporedObjekat> rez = new ArrayList<RasporedObjekat>();
if(rasporedObjekatList==null){
    rasporedObjekatList = new ArrayList<RasporedObjekat>();
}
for(RasporedObjekat ro:rasporedObjekatList){
    if(!ro.getVecernjiProgram()){
        rez.add(ro);
    }
}
return rez;
}


@XmlTransient
public List<RasporedObjekat> rasporedObjekatListPoslePodne(){
List<RasporedObjekat> rez = new ArrayList<RasporedObjekat>();
if(rasporedObjekatList==null){
    rasporedObjekatList = new ArrayList<RasporedObjekat>();
}
for(RasporedObjekat ro:rasporedObjekatList){
    if(ro.getVecernjiProgram()){
        rez.add(ro);
    }
}
return rez;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<DogadjajObjekat> getDogadjajObjekatList() {
    return dogadjajObjekatList;
}

public void setDogadjajObjekatList(List<DogadjajObjekat> dogadjajObjekatList) {
    this.dogadjajObjekatList = dogadjajObjekatList;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<SlikeLokacijaObjekat> getSlikeLokacijaObjekatList() {
    return slikeLokacijaObjekatList;
}

public void setSlikeLokacijaObjekatList(List<SlikeLokacijaObjekat> slikeLokacijaObjekatList) {
    this.slikeLokacijaObjekatList = slikeLokacijaObjekatList;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<RasporedObjekat> getRasporedObjekatList() {
    return rasporedObjekatList;
}

public void setRasporedObjekatList(List<RasporedObjekat> rasporedObjekatList) {
    this.rasporedObjekatList = rasporedObjekatList;
}
```

and i persist it in a rather normal way, or i just think so.

```
utx.begin();
           if(noviObjekat.getIdObjekat() == null){
               em.persist(noviObjekat);
           }else{
               em.merge(noviObjekat);
           }
utx.commit();
```

and i get a pretty weird error

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id_opstina" violates not-null constraint
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO objekat (absolute_path_logo, adresa, kapacitet, korisnicko_ime, lokacija_duzina, lokacija_sirina, maks_broj_slike, naziv, opis, sifra, id_opstina) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [11 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(rs.dzetSet.entiteti.Objekat[ idObjekat=null ])
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You set a generator on the field for "id_objekat" but the exception is for the not-null constraint on "id_opstina".  You will need to set this field yourself or use a returning policy to get it instead:
 http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_for_Returning_Policy